# click on e.currentTarget.id returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Testing in Google Chrome for Mac v80.0.3987.149 (64-bit)

Why does this function return undefined? It doesn't seem to matter where I click...

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
});
```

In contrast, this function gives me the id names I expect...

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Unfortunately, `target.id` doesn't work as desired when there is a div within a div, and I want to detect the click on the outer div.

---

UPDATE: Given the comments I received below, here was the solution for my needs...

```
document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Comment: What element is `event.currentTarget` and does it have ID? Create one big div with background color and ID, no other tags inside. Does it works then? Can you create SO Snippet with this issue?

Comment: If you run `console.log(event.currentTarget)` you may realise why the `id` is `undefined`.

Comment: It's the window object... ? I don't understand. What am I doing differently from this? https://jsfiddle.net/597fym2d/

Comment: replace window with document.getElementById('id to target')

Comment: you are targeting the window so if you click on body and body has no id it returns undefined